# How to collect all possible arguments of an argparse.ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

Given an `argparse.ArgumentParser`, e.g.

**parser.py**

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
p = ArgumentParser()

subs = p.add_subparsers()
a = subs.add_parser('a')
a.add_argument('aa')
b = subs.add_parser('b')
b.add_argument('bb')

p.parse_args()
```

Now, I can call this with ***python parser.py -h / b -h / a -h***, and each call with give me all options relevant for said sub parser. Adding them up together, I can get a full list of all args.

I can do this like this:

```
from parser import p
p.print_help()
```

and then start parsing the output, which is obviously not a good idea.

I can access `p._subparsers` but that didn't give me too much.

**- How to do this the right way?**

*What I eventually want to get: A pytest test, where I can test all options yield a valid response, e.g. `python parser a aa` will actually do `aa`*

Comment: Supplying the argument in the `p.parser_args(['arg_a', 'arg_b'])` is not what you need? Are you also trying to find what arguments exists?

You will be able to do:
```def some_test():
    p.parse_args(['a', 'aa'])
    p.parse_args(['b', 'bb'])```

You will then be able to either `except SystemExit` or derive from ArgumentParser and override the `error` method.

Comment: In test-time, I don't know the args, so I can't give them to the `parse_args`. I can only access the initialized parser, and work my way down from there

Comment: When accessing `p`. You can access its `_actions` list. You can iterate over it and check the types. if its of type `_StoreAction` you can access its dest to check its name. if its `_SubParsersAction` - You can iterate over the inner `choices` and get its Actions. A bit pain but it will work

Comment: @OrY Accessing any attributes beginning with `_` is inherently fragile because these can be changed without notice in future releases. Is there a way using "public" methods?

Comment: @alaniwi I know that it's dangerous but sadly there is no public way to do that. A safer way to achieve what OP wants might be to derive from the ArgumentParser and change the add_argument and (Also add_subparsers and later add_subparser) in a way that each call to those function will keep the new arguments in an externally exposed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
p = ArgumentParser()

subs = p.add_subparsers()
a = subs.add_parser('a')
aa = a.add_argument('aa')
b = subs.add_parser('b')
bb = b.add_argument('bb')

p.parse_args()
```

`add_argument` returns an `Action` object.  These objects are also referenced in the `parser._actions` list, but you can collect the references yourself, either by name or in a list (or dict).  `add_subparsers` is a variant on `add_argument` that creates a special subclass of `Action`, one which has the `add_parser` method.

Try running this code in an interactive session, and look at the objects created.  Most have a `repr` method that shows the key (but not all) attributes.  For actions this will include things like `dest`, `nargs`, `default`, etc.  You can even modify those attributes after creation. `argparse` is written as a normal Python hierarchy of classes.

As for the `_` and `__` attributes - they aren't documented, but that doesn't mean they will be changed at a moment's notice.  Changes appear in `argparse` at a snails pass, with a lot thought given to backward compatibility (though sometimes not enough).  It's easier to change the documentation than the code itself, especially not core things like `_actions`.

But I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do.  Running unittests with `argparse` is somewhat awkward.  You can simulate `args = parse.parse_args(argv)` where `argv` is a list of strings of your choice.  Or you can set `sys.argv[1:]` to a new set of strings.  Or you could create a new `args=argparse.Namespace(...)` object.  Trying to generate all possible argument combinations just based on the `parser` setup sounds like a lot of work, especially when using subparsers.